# How to debug assemblies loaded with a custom .NET Core 2 host?

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, .net-core, visual-studio-debugging

To extend a native application with managed add-on functionality, I've created a custom .NET Core 2.0 host, very similar to what is described in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/netcore-hosting).

So far it runs fine and loads my assembly. It also successfully runs the method delegated to by `ICLRRuntimeHost2.CreateDelegate`; for a test I wrote a "Hello World" into a new file with `System.IO.File.WriteAllText` which appears with that content as expected.

However, I'm a little stumped on how I could actually *debug* the managed code in the assembly I loaded.

- Simply setting a breakpoint there doesn't trigger.
- I also tried to search for specific debug-related property-value pairs to pass to the `ICLRRuntimeHost2.CreateAppDomainWithManager` method, but didn't find any.
- Calling `Debugger.Break` *does* cause the MSVC++ debugger to break ("bla.exe has triggered a breakpoint."), but doesn't step into my managed code or understands anything of it. I guess it's just a common system-native way to break the debugger.
- Or is there something like an "egg file" as known from Python to get Visual Studio to "connect" the managed code with the debugger?

As said, my code is very similar to the docs, and here for reference. `Run` basically loads the coreclr library, gets the GetClrRuntimeHost function from it, instantiates the app domain and runs the delegated managed code. Should the implementation of the few called extra methods or used members be of any concern, I'll add them on request.

```
void ClrHost::Run(wstring const& assembly, wstring const& type, wstring const& method)
{
    // Load the CoreCLR.dll and retrieve the GetCLRRuntimeHost function.
    wstring coreClrFilePath = _runtimeFolder / "coreclr.dll";
    HMODULE coreClr = LoadLibraryExW(coreClrFilePath.c_str(), NULL, 0);
    if (!coreClr)
        throw new ClrHostException(L"Could not load CoreCLR.dll.");
    FnGetCLRRuntimeHost fnGetClrRuntimeHost = (FnGetCLRRuntimeHost)GetProcAddress(coreClr, "GetCLRRuntimeHost");
    if (!fnGetClrRuntimeHost)
        throw new ClrHostException(L"Could not find GetCLRRuntimeHost function.");

    // Instantiate and set up a runtime host.
    if (FAILED(fnGetClrRuntimeHost(IID_ICLRRuntimeHost2, (IUnknown**)&_runtimeHost)))
        throw new ClrHostException(L"Could not retrieve ICLRRuntimeHost2 instance.");
    STARTUP_FLAGS startupFlags = static_cast<STARTUP_FLAGS>(
        STARTUP_FLAGS::STARTUP_CONCURRENT_GC
        | STARTUP_FLAGS::STARTUP_SINGLE_APPDOMAIN
        | STARTUP_FLAGS::STARTUP_LOADER_OPTIMIZATION_SINGLE_DOMAIN);
    if (FAILED(_runtimeHost->SetStartupFlags(startupFlags)))
        throw new ClrHostException(L"Could not set runtime host startup flags.");
    if (FAILED(_runtimeHost->Start()))
        throw new ClrHostException(L"Could not start runtime host.");

    // Instantiate the AppDomain with the configured settings.
    int appDomainFlags = APPDOMAIN_ENABLE_PLATFORM_SPECIFIC_APPS
        | APPDOMAIN_ENABLE_PINVOKE_AND_CLASSIC_COMINTEROP
        | APPDOMAIN_DISABLE_TRANSPARENCY_ENFORCEMENT;
    wstring tpaAssemblies = ConcatenatePaths(GetAssembliesFromFolder(_runtimeFolder));
    wstring assemblyFolders = ConcatenatePaths(_assemblyFolders);
    wstring nativeLibFolders = ConcatenatePaths(_nativeLibFolders);
    LPCWSTR propertyKeys[] = {
        L"TRUSTED_PLATFORM_ASSEMBLIES",
        L"APP_PATHS",
        L"APP_NI_PATHS",
        L"NATIVE_DLL_SEARCH_DIRECTORIES",
        L"PLATFORM_RESOURCE_ROOTS",
        L"AppDomainCompatSwitch"
    };
    LPCWSTR propertyValues[] = {
        tpaAssemblies.c_str(),
        assemblyFolders.c_str(),
        assemblyFolders.c_str(),
        nativeLibFolders.c_str(),
        assemblyFolders.c_str(),
        L"UseLatestBehaviorWhenTFMNotSpecified"
    };
    if (FAILED(_runtimeHost->CreateAppDomainWithManager(L"IDA.NET AppDomain", appDomainFlags, NULL, NULL,
        sizeof(propertyKeys) / sizeof(LPCWSTR), propertyKeys, propertyValues, &_appDomainID)))
    {
        throw new ClrHostException(L"Could not create AppDomain.");
    }

    // Get a delegate for the managed static method.
    void *fnDelegate = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = _runtimeHost->CreateDelegate(_appDomainID, assembly.c_str(), type.c_str(), method.c_str(),
        (INT_PTR*)&fnDelegate);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        throw new ClrHostException(L"Could not run " + type + L"." + method + L" in " + assembly + L".");

    // Execute the managed code.
    ((RunSignature*)fnDelegate)();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized it is simpler than expected!

Right now, I always used my native C++ project (the one which hosts .NET Core) as the startup project in Visual Studio.

However, by changing the startup project to the managed C# library by creating a startup profile launching the external native executable instead of "launching" my library, makes it possible to debug and step through the managed code.

You can set up such a startup profile in the project properties under "Debug", or add a typical .NET Core `Properties\launchSettings.json` to your managed project root, storing contents like this:

```
{
"profiles": {
    "Any profile name (typically the project name)": {
    "commandName": "Executable",
    "executablePath": "C:\\FullNativeExecutablePath\\AndFileName.exe",
    "workingDirectory": "C:\\FullNativeExecutablePath"
    }
}
}
```